# Swift WebViews not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, webview, nsurl

I have done lots of research, yet I am stilling having the same problem. I am trying to load a website onto a web view in swift, although every time I run the project, it is giving me the following error message:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

The following two lines of code are what I am attempting to use to load the url onto the web view. I want to let you know that these 2 lines of code came from the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcVv1N1hReQ. Here are the lines of code:

```
var URL = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
petInfo.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))
```

In case you are wondering what the outlet for petInfo looks like, it is displayed in the following block of code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var petInfo: UIWebView!
```

The outlet is getting initialized immediately before the viewDidLoad() function. The url is being loaded inside the viewDidLoad() function. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured the answer out. The problem was that my WebView was equal to nil, although my function was requesting a value, so the app crashed. Instead of using the ! to unwrap the outlet, I changed it to the following:

```
if let pet = petInfo{
     //do normal function stuff like loading the web views.
}
```

I want to thank you for the answer, although it was not what I was looking for. If anybody doesn't understand the code below, just type up a comment (make sure to add +Andrew_Wilson214) and then I will explain it to you further.

Comment: Your petInfo variable is still nil and the web view is not loading. You still need to connect the UI WebView to your petInfo variable. Right click (or Control-click) from the WebView in the storyboard to the ViewController.swift file.  Make sure that the circle in the gutter next to the petInfo declaration is filled.

Comment: I know it is connected. I know it works. I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have not connected the WebView to the IBOutlet in your ViewController. In the screenshot below you will see that I have defined `@IBOutlet weak var petInfo: UIWebView` but the grey circle in the gutter next to that line is not filled.  It is not connected to the UI element yet. Also check your console to see if get the same fatal error '`unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`'.

[image]

Comment: +Price Ringo Although this was not the answer I was looking for ( I am displaying the answer  in the answer above here) I still appreciate you helping me try to figure this out. I am sure your solution work just fine, although the solution above is what I have decided to use. Thank you for your consideration in which you answered this question. Have a nice day!